# Vurtial scrolling with images from CDN

Tags: image, vue.js, performance

I've implemented a virtual scroller in Vue with a grid layout, where each item contains an image. While scrolling down, items load in and disappear using an v-if, but when scrolling back up, the vanished items reappear, causing the images to be rendered again.

This results in additional fetch calls for the same images, slowing down the performance. Is there a way to prevent the need for refetching the images when they reappear?

Comment: The problem is specific to your case and cannot be asked in general. It's unknown what cdn you're talking about and how the scroller is implemented. The most straightforward way is to make sure a server enables caching so the images are cached in a browser and not reloaded